# MT5 python buy order off the chart

Tags: python-3.x, metatrader5

While executing a python script to make some trades in mT5 using a demo account I face an odd behaviour : the buy order is literally off the chart. Does anyone had this issue, is it a volatility phenomena or am I not using the right order type? Thanks ;)

I have a screenshot but it seems I don’t have the right to post it.

Comment: It would almost certainty be a good idea to include the **text** based code that you are using as long as it is not "too" long. Stating that there is some odd behavior without additional context makes it almost impossible to provide an answer.

Comment: True, thanks Jon. I actually found out why. The spread goes crazy at arbitrage time.